# how to get value from array

Tags: php, api, sorting, arr

how to get value from array in php from api 
here is my code

```
 $data = callBitAPI('GET','https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms='.strtoupper($bc->slug).'&tsyms=USD');

        if(!empty($data)){

            $data = json_decode($data,true);
          //  echo '<pre>';
          // print_r($data);
            $data = getRelevantCryptoArray($data,$bc->slug);


        }
```

and here is my result
Please see Attachment 
http://prntscr.com/k7hawi

Answer (score 1):

Um... simply

```
$price = $data['RAW']['BTC']['USD']['PRICE'];
print_r($price);
```

unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Thanx Sir its working

Answer (score 0):

dd($data['RAW']['BTC']['USD']['PRICE']) and see the result

Comment: Thanx Sir its working